# Recursive QuickSort in java not working

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, quicksort, partition

I am trying to implement a quicksort in java which has the last element of the array as a pivot. However, it does not seem to be working even though on paper it should..

This is the output:

```
before sort: 5 2 3 1 4 

after sort: 3 2 4 5 1
```

The expected output would be 1,2,3,4,5 but that doesn't seem to be happening.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A[] = {5,2,3,1,0};
    ArrayUtils.printArray("before sort", A);
    quick_sort(A, 0, A.length-1);
    ArrayUtils.printArray("after sort", A);
}

public static void quick_sort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(A, p, r);
        quick_sort(A, p, q-1);
        quick_sort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}
```

I have tracked the problem down to be in partition with the debugger, but I cannot seem to find where it is. It seems for loop sometimes will produce a wrong i, but sometimes it works correctly.. I am not sure, that is why i am asking.

```
public static int partition(int A[], int p, int r) {
    int x = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    for(int j = p; j < r-1; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1;
            int temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = A[r];
    A[r] = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = temp;
    return i + 1;
}
```

where printArray() is

```
public static void printArray(String name, int[] array) {
    if (array.length >= 10) {
        System.out.print(name + ": \n");
    } else {
        System.out.print(name + ": ");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 0) {
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your partition algorithm looks is based on the Lomuto partition scheme in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). However, in Wikipedia, the pseudo-code says `for j := lo to hi - 1`, which is based on Pascal syntax.  In Pascal-like languages, that means that the last value of `j` is `hi - 1`. In C-like languages such as Java, we usually make the upper bound the value *after* the last value the index will have, instead of the last value. That means that in your code, `j` will never actually have the value `hi - 1`.  Fixing the `for` loop to make sure `j` does take the value `r-1` makes things work, with your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the for loop was iterating one time less than it should and it was pure luck that it worked on some occasions.